# How to create a theme creator application(similar to Go Launcher Theme Maker) for android?

Tags: android, android-theme

I want to develop theme maker just similar to the "Go Launcher Theme Maker"(http://www.goforandroid.com/GDTEn/soft.aspx?softid=21&nav=2) for Android. Is anybody aware how "Go Launcher" is creating the .apk file after creating a new theme. Can any one guide me how to proceed? Any help in this regard will be well appreciated.